# Discord Embed Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I get the error Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

My script is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "!";


client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send(` Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`);
    }
    if (command === 'embed') {
        const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Test Title')
        .setURL('https://youtube.com/')
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)

    message.channel.send(embed1)
    }
})
```

If you can help, thank you.

This error is about the embed part.

Comment: Is there any other code that has "client" in it?

Comment: There is no client as a property in the provided code. So check the error properly and see where it says.

Answer (score 1):

Code works fine but it is missing `client.login(TOKEN)` at the end. This use token from your discord bot to login.